# LINQ build in time Silverlight c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq

I have a method like this:

The parameteres can be null

```
public string getAll(string d1, string d2, string d3){
     Do the linq
}
```

I want to do a linq query if d1 is no null, another if d2 is not null, another if d1 and d2 is no null and all the posible convinations whit the parameters.

I dont want to do:

```
if(d1 != null)
//linq opt1
if(d2 != null
//linq opt2
if(d1 != null && d2 != null)
//linq opt3
```

please :(

Comment: And what problem are you having, other than it'll be somewhat messy code?

Comment: Yeah,there's no way to do that in one "line of code"?

Comment: God help you if you add a fourth parameter.

Comment: Would something like this be what you are looking for? http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Generally the queries in these types of questions have -some- commonality (otherwise, why use one method?).  Perhaps you are looking for conditional filtering.

```
public string getAll(string d1, string d2, string d3)
{
   using(CustomDataContext dc = new CustomDataContext())
   {
     IQueryable<Customer> query = dc.Customers;
     if (d1 != null)
     {
       query = query.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(d1));
     }
     if (d2 != null)
     {
       query = query.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderNumber == d2));
     }
     if (d3 != null)
     {
       query = query.Where(c => c.FavoriteColor == d3);
     }
     query =
        from c in query
        order c by c.Name
        select c;

     List<Customer> results = query.Take(5).ToList();
     string answer = SomeMethod(results);
     return answer;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string getAll(string d1, string d2, string d3){
     if (d1 == null)
      //Do LINQ
     if (d2 == null)
      //Do LINQ
     if (d3 == null)
      //Do LINQ

      if (d1 == null && d2 == null && d3 != null)
       //Do LINQ
      if (d1 == null && d2 != null && d3 == null)
       //Do LINQ
      if (d1 != null && d2 == null && d3 != null)
       //Do LINQ
}
```

This isn't copy and paste but you should get the idea. Need to do some checks so that both groups don't execute.

Comment: This is wath I want to avoid ;)

Comment: Think about it, how else are you going to do it. You need to do checks for each parameter. You may be able to use a few switches to make it more elegant, but your still going to be writing some code.

Comment: :( 3! posibilities? if I have 8 paramethers then I have to write 8! posibilities?????

Comment: Your using one method to handle many different situations, like I stated before, there is more elegant ways of writing it, but I feel that it's still going to be a mound of code.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of doing it in one line, you could use nested ternary statements...

```
var result = d1==null?d2==null?/*Linq when both are null*/:/*Linq when d1 is null but d2 isn't*/:/*linq when neither d1 and d2 are null*/;
```

This example doesn't have 3 parameters, but just keep nesting away :)